# Elegant way of creating a document class that changes between styles back and forth

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, typography

I would like to create a book class, say `class.cls`, such that

1. It automatically acquires some style depending on the location of the code inside the main document. Something like one style for each: `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`.
2. In fact, I might even want to change the style within `\frontmatter`, so I would like some kind of command that would alternate between already defined styles inside `class.cls`.

For concreteness, let's take the `\pagestyle` command or the `\titleformat`. I would like to do something like the following.

```
  \documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extbook} 
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
  \usepackage{psvectorian}

  \begin{document}

  \frontmatter
  \pagestyle{empty}

  \input{file1.tex}

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}

  \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
               {\huge\normalfont\bfseries}
               {}{0pt}{\centering \psvectorian[scale=0.5]{60}}
               \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.5cm}{20pt}

  \input{file.2}

  \mainmatter

  \pagestyle{empty}

  \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
               {\huge\normalfont\bfseries}
               \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.5cm}{20pt}

  \input{file.3}

  \end{document}
```

So it changes the chapter, heading and footing style within `\frontmatter` and again when going to `\mainmatter`.

Of course, I could create one `.cls` file with the initial settings and then change those ones in the middle of the main document. I would, however, like a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pack all the command defining a so called style in a command (one per style) defined in the preamble ? To make this more robust and efficient it could be useful to save the initial settings with `\let` or `xargs`'s command `\newcommandx` to reset them at the entrance of the styling macros.

Comment: @Jhor Do you mean some big command with a bunch of if's? I don't know how to detect whether the code is inside say `\mainmatter`. Actually I'm not sure if I can even deal properly with the second point by such means. I would need to define a variable and ask for some input. I'm not sure if I can do that inside a `.cls` file...

Comment: If the changes must occur on l'y when entering front/main/back- latter, you won't crête macros my redefine the standard macros.

Comment: Yes there is a test to detect the main matter. Add `\meaning\chapter` and/or `\meaning\@makechapter` in your document and you will see how it is used to alter the handling of chapters between front and main  matter.

Comment: @Jhor Hmm... I can't understand your second comment. Is there any variable that records whether the document is inside front\main\backmatter? I'm not very proficient with TeX. I mean something analogous to when you echo the value of some variable in bash...

Comment: @Jhor Ah! Ok! Thanks. What about the front\backmatter? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need any variable , iir is a boolean alresy defined in standard LaTeX. If you tell me whether the change od style must occurs at arbitrary places or only when switching from front to main and main to back, I will pride you with a full anwer ( tomorow, as it's night here).

Comment: @Jhor I would like both as I mentioned in the two distinct items. Something that I can manually change within the main document (by providing some command defined in the class file) and something predefined that automatically changes when one transit across front\main\backmatter. Looking forward to your answer, then!

Comment: you don' need a test at all, if you pu all your backmatter settings in to a command callable in the document, say `\styleA`  Then define `\backmatter` in your class to do `... exising definittion..\styleA`  and similarly define `\mainmatter` to end `\styleB`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. So I would need to redefine `\backmatter`. Do you mean something like `\renewcommand{\backmatter}{\backmatter\StyleA}` or would it be more complicated?

Comment: well `\let\oldbackmatter\backmatter\renewcommand{\backmatter}{\oldbackmatter\StyleA}` but you said you were defining a class, so you get to define `\backmatter` you don't necessarily have an existing definition to redefine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the reply. Couldn't I just use `\LoadClass[14pt, a4paper]{extbook}` before the `\renewcommand` inside the `.cls` file and use the regular `\backmatter`?

Comment: yes if you want,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MWE which implements, I think, all your requirements:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extbook} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % << added for a better result
\usepackage{lmodern}      % << but optionnal
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}     % << option explicit removed
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\usepackage{etoolbox}     % needed for \appto and \ifstrequal

% packages & settings  for demonstration purpose, 
%not needed  for real use
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{.1pt}
% end of packages & settings  for demonstration purpose

\makeatletter  % enable the use of @ character

% defining the regular style as in book or in extbook
\newcommand\setStyleRegular[1][]{%
   % style change mid of page doesn't really make sense  
   % to override, pass "samepage"
   \ifstrequal{#1){samepage}{\relax}%
   {if@openright\cleardoublepage \else \clearpage\fi}
   \pagestyle{headings}
   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}%
      {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
   \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
    \if@mainmatter 
        \renewcommand\thepage{\roman{page}}
    \else 
        \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
    \fi
}

% defining a fancy style
\newcommand\setStyleFancy[1][]{%
   \setlength{\headheight}{18pt}
   % style change mid of page doesn't really make sense  
   % to override, pass "samepage"
   \ifstrequal{#1){samepage}{\relax}%
   {if@openright\cleardoublepage \else \clearpage\fi}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
   \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
   \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
   % for real use, remove the \fbox but keep the \parboxb
   \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\huge\normalfont\bfseries}%
      {\thechapter}{20pt}{}%
     [\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\psvectorian[scale=0.5]{60}}}]
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.5cm}{20pt}  
    \if@mainmatter 
        \renewcommand\thepage{\roman{page}}
    \else 
        \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
    \fi
}

% add here any other custom style(s)
\makeatother

%% automatic switch when changing the *-matter
%% no additionnal page changes are needed here
\appto{\frontmatter}{\setStyleRegular[samepage]}
\appto{\mainmatter}{\setStyleFancy[samepage]}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Regular in frontmatter}
\section*{A starred section (front)}
\lipsum[1-2]
    
\setStyleFancy

\chapter{Fancy in frontmatter}
\section*{Another starred section  (front)}
\lipsum[7-11]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Fancy in mainmatter}
\section{A  section (main)}
\lipsum[1-2]
    
\setStyleRegular

\chapter{Regular in maintmatter}
\section{Another section  (main)}
\lipsum[7-11]

\end{document}
```

- They were some oddities in your use of `\titleformat` and of `\psvectorian` that have been corrected.
- As i don't have your `file1,2,3`, I replaced them by `lipsum` dummy text
- I added the `\thechapter` in the fancy setup, but if you don't need it, you can remove or customize it; in any case it won't appear in the frontmatter chapters
- Of course this (must) be customized, for example to add more styles, or tweak the style change on `\frontmatter` or `\mainmatter` or, if needed, extend it to `\backmatter`
- All the code contained between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` could  be put in an `\input`-ed .tex file, or a custom package or class, but the creation of the latter is a completely different question, that is widely documented on the web, or deserves another post here.